# Identifying the methods associated with a generic function

Tags: r

Is as.character a generic function? It says it is generic in its description detail section. However when I try to view its methods using the following code I obtain:

```
showMethods(as.character)
Function "as.character":<not an S4 generic function>
```

What is an S4 generic function? When I look at the description of a function I look at the detail section to see whether it is generic or not. Is that the correct approach? I

Comment: You can use `methods('as.character')` to view all the methods

Comment: how can I view all generic functions in R? I am doing the as. functions one at a time!

Comment: There's no easy way to view all the generic functions.  One way to do it would be to step through the search list, get each function one at a time, and then look for `UseMethod` in their bodies.  This would be slow, and would miss a few (including `as.character`, because it's a `.Primitive` function, and the equivalent of `UseMethod` is being done in C code.)

Comment: generic function -> primitive function? One way implication?